# Outer function returns an inner function with access to values from outer function

Tags: javascript, lexical-scope

I need to create a function which I will pass to my database server. The returned function will take a single item as a parameter and compare that item to a list of requirements.

For this I need a function generating function that takes an array as it's argument and returns the inner function which has that array built in to it.

Here's an example:

```
function create_query (list_of_requirements) {
  return function (item) {
    var is_match = true
    // the next function sets is_match to false if the item fails
    list_of_requirements.forEach(check_if_item_meets_requirement)
    return is_match
  }
}
```

An example of using this:

```
function search (parsed_user_string) {
  db.get(create_query(parsed_user_string)).then(function(results){
    show_results(results)
  })
}
```

How can I build the list of requirements into the inner function?

Comment: It looks like you're already doing that. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: I see two issues: you're never calling the function that `create_query()` returns. Second, I assume `db.get()` expects its argument to be a query string, but your function just returns a boolean.

Comment: `check_if_item_meets_requirements` also needs to be in the scope of the inner function so it can assign to `is_match`.

Comment: If the argument to `db.get` is supposed to be a callback, then it looks like you're calling it correctly.

Comment: db.get needed to take a function as it's argument, and returns a promise.

my answer below addresses the issues using a closure.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use a closure.

Here's a simpler example of a solution.

```
function makePrinter (num) {
  (return function () {
    print(num)
    })
}
```

and then:

```
var print5 = makePrinter(5)
print5() > prints 5!
```

I still don't quite get how closures accomplish this, but there it is.